# Centralização de botões em uma div não funciona

Tags: css, html5

Criei uma div contendo vários botões, e setei em dois desses botões (os da segunda linha de botões) o atributo `align = "center"`, no html mesmo. Mas foi a mesma coisa que nada, eles continuam aparecendo alinhados à esquerda da div. O que pode ser ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head><title> Banco Online </title>

    <link rel="StyleSheet"
    href="EstiloBotao.css"
    type="text/css" />

    <link rel="StyleSheet"
    href="EstiloMenu.css"
    type="text/css" />

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="menu" id="menu1">
            <button class="botao" onClick="mudaMenu('menu1', 'menu2')">Iniciar</button>
        </div>

        <div class="menu" id="menu2" style="display:none">
            <button class="botao"> Saldo </button>
            <button class="botao" > Extratos </button>
            <button class="botao" > Saques </button>
            <br>   <!-- ESSES DOIS BOTÕES ABAIXO NÃO FICAM CENTRALIZADOS NA 
                     DIV-->
            <br>
            <button class="botao" align="center" > Depósitos </button>
            <button class="botao" align="center"> Transferências </button>
        </div>
...... resto do código
```

O css da div de menu:

```
body, html {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
      }
      .menu{
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
      }
```

O css do estilo do botão:

```
botao{
        background:#6E6E6E;
        color:gold;
        font-size:22px;
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-weight:bold;
        height:100px; width:200px;
        border-color:#D8D8D8;
        border-radius:20px;
        border-width:6px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, algumas considerações sobre o jeito que você está tentando aplicar estilos no seu layout:

1) `align="center"` está obsoleto no `HTML5`;

2) um elemento não deveria "se alinhar", a não ser que você mude o `position`, `margin`, etc dele, é mais simples colocar dentro de um *container*, um `div` por exemplo, que esse sim alinhe os elementos dentro dele (como na sugestão abaixo)

3) existem diversas formas de alinhar um elemento, sugiro que leia esse link do W3C: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Agora uma sugestão para o seu problema: coloque os botões que quer alinhar num `div`, e coloque nesse `div` o alinhamento centralizado, pois tudo que está dentro ficará alinhado. Mantive seus estilos, só inclui uma borda no menu para evidenciar o alinhamento.

```css
body, html {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
      }
      .menu{
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
        border: solid 1px;
        width: 300px;
      }
      botao{
        background:#6E6E6E;
        color:gold;
        font-size:22px;
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-weight:bold;
        height:100px; width:200px;
        border-color:#D8D8D8;
        border-radius:20px;
        border-width:6px;
    }
    .centralizar {
      width: 100%; 
      text-align: center
    }
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menu2">
    <button class="botao"> Saldo </button>
    <button class="botao" > Extratos </button>
    <button class="botao" > Saques </button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="centralizar">
      <button class="botao" > Depósitos </button>
      <button class="botao"> Transferências </button>
    </div>     
</div>
```